# Dot product of a matrix columns with vector to show no solutions to $A\cdot x = b$

Tags: linear-algebra

In G. Strangs's Introduction to Linear Algebra, 5th, 2.1B of the sample exercises gives equations:

$${x + 3y + 5z = 4}$$
$${x + 2y - 3z = 5}$$
    $${2x + 5y + 2z = 8}$$

One of the questions asks to take the dot product of each column of matrix A of coefficients associated with the system of equations above with vector $${y=(1,1,-1)}$$ as well as the dot product of $${y\cdot b}$$ where ${b = (4, 5, 8)}$ and based on the results show that no combination of columns equals ${b}$.

The solution presented shows that each dot product ${Col1\cdot y}$, ${Col2\cdot y}$, and ${Col3\cdot y}$ is 0 while ${y\cdot b = 1}$ which implies ${0 = 1}$ therefore no solution exists.

I do not understand what this process is and why the dot product of the columns with ${y}$ and that of ${b}$ with ${y}$ need to be equal otherwise there are no solutions. Could someone explain this to me?

Comment: The 3 equations say that the right hand column is a linear combination of the columns of A. Assuming that is the case, your dot product procedure shows that such a linear combination cannot be formed.

Comment: Essentially y is orthogonal to all the vectors in the column space of A, but is not orthogonal to b, hence b must be constructed from vectors not lying in the column space of A.

Comment: What I understand is this, a solution vector x is a vector which creates a linear combination of the columns of A. Alternatively, a system of equations can be thought about as the dot product of each row of the coefficient matrix with the solution vector x. In this specific case as far as I understand we are doing neither. y is a particularly chosen vector and we take the dot product not of a row with it, but of a column with it. If y in this example acts like a potential solution x, then in my mind this only shows that y is not a solution, not that no solutions exist whatsoever. I'm confused.

Comment: This all sounds a bizarrely complicated way of going about things. If you add the first two equations you get $2x+5y+2z=9$, which contradicts the third equation, so no solutions.

Comment: Maybe don't call the vector y, call it V. It is not a solution, it is simply a device which shows that the right hand side cannot be written as a linear combination of the columns of A.

Comment: @almagast the column space viewpoint is a favourite of Strang I think.

Comment: Having seen Delong's solution I now understand the 'device'. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $c_{1},c_{2},c_{3}$ be the column vectors. Suppose the system has a solution $(x_{0},y_{0},z_{0})$. Then $x_{0}c_{1}+y_{0}c_{2}+z_{0}c_{3}=b$. So $y\cdot (x_{0}c_{1}+y_{0}c_{2}+z_{0}c_{3})=y\cdot b$. Hence $x_{0}(y\cdot c_{1})+y_{0}(y\cdot c_{2})+z_{0}(y\cdot c_{3})=y\cdot b$. So $0=1$, contradiction.